# maximum matching in general graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures

How to justify the role of blossom in Edmond's blossom algorithm for maximum matching? odd cycles also can be covered in augmenting path.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what your question is? Edmonds proves that his algorithm works. What are you looking for in an answer?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm in this algorithm. if we don't consider blossom separately. Just find the augmenting paths then why it is wrong?

Comment: Blossoms are used to find these augmenting paths.